# I am Unable to Uninstall an Applications like Node or Atom in OS X

Tags: mac, applications, macos

I just bought a Macbook Pro and I'm new to OSX. I can't uninstall applications like Node, Atom, etc. They are not shown in my Application folder  nor in the Launcher.  How can i delete them?'

Below is screenshot of my Applications folder.  However, if I search for Atom using Spotlight,  I can access it from there. 
[image]

Comment: How have you installed these applications? If you mean just downloaded them, they might still be in you Downloads folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried emptying your trash? Spotlight can find and open (IIRC) applications that remain in trash.

If after your trash is emptied *and* you still see Atom or Node, try, in Terminal:

```
sudo find / -iname 'thing'
```

in which you should substitute `thing` with your search query.

**EDIT:** in Spotlight, when you hold <kbd>Command</kbd>, does it show a path at the bottom of the spotlight window?

**EDIT 2:** As per @Lizzan's comment, do check your Downloads, Documents, and any other user-related folders.

Comment: it says Santoshs-MacBook-Pro:~ santosh$ find / -iname 'atom'
find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /.fseventsd: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied
 and my trash is empty i had installed those app but never uninstall them

Comment: Hold on, are you trying to *find the app* or *remove the app*?

Comment: To remove those messages just prepend a `sudo` to the command

Comment: i can find them using spotlight i want to remove them completely

Comment: Look at my edit; when you press Command, does a path bar show at the bottom of the Spotlight window?